# scp does not auto-complete in the same way as other commands

Tags: tcsh

I am using tcsh. I found that when I do
`scp my`tab, it doesn't autocomplete to `my-file.txt` under the current directory 
I have to prefix a `./` there to make it complete.
This seems to only happen with `scp`. I tried other commands, it seems to work fine.

I find that `scp` <kbd>tab</kbd> gives me
the value of of `$HOSTNAME` (i.e. the current hostname) `localhost`

So it looks like it's trying to match the hostname, don't know why..

**added in response to comment:**

```
 ~/temp/test>ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 liw liw 4096 Jul 21 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 liw liw 8192 Jul 21 15:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 liw liw    0 Jul 21 15:16 my_file.txt

~>more .cshrc.user 
set prompt="%n@%m %~%#"

set path=($HOME/bin $path)

if (-o $HOME/.aliases) source $HOME/.aliases

set filec
set autolist
set autoexpand
set addsuffix

bindkey ^r i-search-back

~> complete scp
'c%*@*:%`set q=$:-0;set q="$q:s/@/ /";set q="$q:s/:/ /";set q=($q " ");ssh $q[2] -l $q[1] ls -dp $q[3]\*`%' 'c%*:%`set q=$:-0;set q="$q:s/:/ /";set q=($q " ");ssh $q[1] ls -dp $q[2]\*`%' 'c%*@%$hosts%:' 'C@[./$~]*@f@' 'n/*/$hosts/:'
```

Comment: An ls of the directory in question might be helpful.  I suspect that you have >1 files starting with my preventing the autocomplete from adding anything further.

Comment: Post your `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc`

Comment: @mdpc But then `./my[TAB]` wouldn't work any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is almost certainly a systemwide tcsh configuration file in /etc that has a special `complete` command defined for `scp`. The easiest way to check this is to type

```
complete
```

which will list all the custom completions. The custom completion directives are kinda complicated, but the intention is probably that if you are using `scp` at least one of the arguments wants to have a hostname in the filepath. You can then try to figure out that arcana or just add

```
uncomplete scp
```

to your `~/.tcshrc` and fly on manual-override for that one command.

Comment: You are right! I updated my question with "complete scp"

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think I have now seen code that is marginally harder to make sense of than Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Auto complete will try to match all entries in your hosts file. I once did an auto complete and got "sexyladies.com" and thought my system was compromised as I never visited that site.

It wasn't, I had a hosts file setup with about 20k entries of sites I wanted to block. So every time I do an auto complete it goes through that list.